# Ruby "&&" causes internal server error on Rails ajax call and "and" doesn't. What's the difference between the two?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery, operators, operator-precedence

I'm building my first Rails app and I'm using JQuery to make an ajax POST request to update a resource. I'm sending `_method: "PATCH"` and the correct controller is being executed:

```
  def update
    @buddyship = Buddyship.find(params[:id])
    if @buddyship.involve? current_user && @buddyship.update(buddyship_params)
      render json: { success: true }
    else
      render json: { success: false }, :status => 500
    end
  end
```

I'm testing the standard use case first, where the relationship does involve the current user, so the first part of the condition evaluates to `true`. The second does too, I know it because I tried

```
def update
  @buddyship = Buddyship.find(params[:id])
  bool = @buddyship.update(buddyship_params)
  logger.debug "bool: "+bool.to_s
  if @buddyship.involve? current_user && bool
    render json: { success: true }
  else
    render json: { success: false }, :status => 500
  end
end
```

and in the logs I got `bool: true`. Plus, the record still gets updated in the database. Still somehow I get Internal Server Error instead of success.

If I simply use `and` instead of `&&`, everything works as I expected.

```
if @buddyship.involve? current_user && @buddyship.update(buddyship_params)
```

I understand that `and` has lower precedence than `&&`, and that the assignment operator `=` is in between. But in this context this doesn't seem to be relevant, after all there's only one operator! So it's not competing for precedence with anything else. It seems pretty straightforward. What am I getting wrong???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`&&` has strong precedence and `and` has low precedence.

```
@buddyship.involve? current_user && @buddyship.update(buddyship_params)
```

is the same as

```
@buddyship.involve?(current_user && @buddyship.update(buddyship_params))
```

and

```
@buddyship.involve? current_user and @buddyship.update(buddyship_params)
```

is the same as

```
@buddyship.involve?(current_user) and @buddyship.update(buddyship_params)
```

Comment: Damn, how naive of me to think there was only one possibility. That was it, thanks!

Comment: Isn't `@buddyship.involve?(current_user) ...` identical in meaning to `@buddyship.involve? current_user ...` for all values of `...`? Did you mean `(@buddyship.involve? current_user)`? (I know no ruby - this is just a guess!)

Comment: @Eric I have no idea what you are writing about, but all three expressions you wrote are equivalent.

Comment: What I'm asking here is whether `@buddyship.involve?(current_user) && foo()` is any different from `@buddyship.involve? current_user && foo()`. Does that mean adding a single space changes the meaning? `@buddyship.involve? (current_user) && foo()`

Comment: @Eric Yes, they are different. A parenthesis has two meanings in Ruby. If it is adjacent to a method, then it means the delimiters for arguments. If there are spaces in between, it means to give higher precedence. `foo(a) && b` unambiguously means that the argument for `foo` is `a`. `foo (a) && b` does not. Unlike what is in your mind, my addition of parentheses clarifies the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Use braces to wrap them as the spaces may break logic.

Change this

```
if @buddyship.involve? current_user && @buddyship.update(buddyship_params)
```

To

```
if (@buddyship.involve? current_user) && (@buddyship.update buddyship_params)
```

Comment: Don't use [braces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braces_%28punctuation%29#Braces) (`{}`), use [parenthesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parenthesis#Parentheses_.28_.29) (`()`).

Comment: Also, I'd say `@buddyship.involve?(current_user) && @buddyship.update(buddyship_params)` is more appropriate than
`(@buddyship.involve? current_user) && (@buddyship.update buddyship_params)`.